# Ajax Post method not detected in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I'm discovering Ajax with Django and cannot to make them work.
Before I continue, the project directory looks like this:

```
mySite
|
|-> myApp
    |-> views.py
    |-> urls.py
    | ... // other py-files and directories
|-> mySite
    |-> urls.py
    | ... // other py-files
```

When I run the site and trigger the event for sending an Ajax request, I get a status 200 code but the function in views.py doesn't get executed so I assume that my urls.py is not properly configured. The Javascript implementing the Ajax post:

```
function sendReq(){
      console.log('AJX');
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax_test',
        data:{
          name: 'AjaxReq',
          val: '...',
          csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
        },
        sucess:function(){
          console.log('SUCCES!');
        }
      });
      console.log('AJX done');
    }
```

The urls.py of myApp:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^ajax_test', views.ajax_test, name='ajax_test'),
]
```

The urls.py of mySite:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^',include('myApp.urls')),
]
```

And finally the views.py of myApp:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'myApp/index.html')

def ajax_test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name', None)
        val = request.POST.get('val', None)
        print(name + ': ' + val)
```

I found different solution but seemed outdated. Can someone point out how to correctly link everything?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should run with DEBUG=True, then the console would show that you have errors in your Python code; `get` is a method, you need to call it with parentheses: `request.POST.get('name')`

Comment: Even by changing the parentheses the same result occurs. Thanks for the debug, I didn't know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the *order* of your `urls.py` of myApp.  The first route that matches will run.  From the Django docs:

[Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request)

Put your first route last, after the more specific ones.